# Convert date (YYYY-MM-DD) to day of year (0-364)

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a column of data in a pandas `dataframe` containing dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I need to create a column containing these dates converted to a single number representing the day of year (0-364).

Comment: Do you have to count February 29 on Leap years ?

Comment: @dgp I just have information for 2019!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> text = "2020-01-19"
>>> (datetime.datetime.strptime(text, "%Y-%m-%d")-datetime.datetime.strptime(f" {text[:4]}-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")).days
18
```

This works.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Pandas [dayofyear](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.dayofyear.html#pandas-period-dayofyear)

Like this,

An example I had laying around:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ "lead_date" : ["2019-12-28" , "2019-12-23"] ,
                    "Received_date" : ["2019-12-15" , "2019-12-21"  ]  })
df['lead_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['lead_date'])


df['dayofyear'] = df['lead_date'].dt.dayofyear
print(df.head())
```

results,

```
   lead_date Received_date  dayofyear
0 2019-12-28    2019-12-15        362
1 2019-12-23    2019-12-21        357
```